# 59 vs 60 hertz on external display via DisplayPort

Tags: thinkpad, external-display, displayport, refresh-rate

Don't know if this is a really specific question or you'll help me out. Please do. I just bought a DeLock DisplayPort cable for my Lenovo T500. Tried to use it with the in-built Intel MHD4500, no use. With the ATI HD3650 (you can switch between the two vga on this machine) I get a normal picture, but only on 59hz. On 60 I get a smaller desktop size (strange).

Any idea what can cause this? Will I have any problem if I use the 59hz?

(Was using the display with a VGA cable but I get a blurry picture with that (dont matter what device I attach, VGA is like this on this display) and thats why I wanted to change.)

(Edit: I'll reinstall my laptop soon, because only 2.5gb gets recognised from the 4gb memory. Don't think this helps anyway, just wanted to mention it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it's a simple Windows/ATI bug. Well.. ATI + display drivers.. =)

Comment: Excuse me? What was a bug? Can you please elaborate on what you discovered in case others can use the information? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, sure. The display refresh rate is set correctly. 59 hz means 60 hz here. It only gets displayed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

59 MHz is fine. The option is available to prevent such things as the screen strobing at the same speed as fluorescent lights in the room, for example, and making strange effects seem to appear on the screen, possibly even flashes. It is probably better at 59.

Different frequencies will all give different screen sizes due to the differing range of the screen scans. Monitors have settings for that purpose to center and change the outer dimensions of the displayed image.

(After reinstalling, your machine will still have the same reported RAM as it does now.)

Comment: 59MHz! I guess I need a better graphics card - 60fps simply won't do on that ;)